# Why isnt my code detecting values in a column from a csv?

Tags: python, csv

I have a column called `pclass` with values of either `'1', '2' or '3'`.
I am using `python` to read how many instances of each value there are.

And then display them as a percentage (%) of the total. It is working for values of `'1'` but not for `'2'` and `'3'`.

What am I doing wrong?*

My code is below:

```
import csv
pclass = 0
pclass1 = [1]
pclass2 = [2]
pclass3 = [3]

pclass1_values = 0
pclass2_values = 0
pclass3_values = 0

total = 891

with open('titanic-new.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')
    next(csv_reader, None)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if int(row[pclass]) in pclass1:
            pclass1_values += 1
    for row in csv_reader:
        if int(row[pclass]) in pclass2:
            pclass2_values += 1
    for row in csv_reader:
        if int(row[pclass]) in pclass3:
            pclass3_values += 1

    print('total: {}, pclass1: {} ({:.2f}%)'.format(total, pclass1_values,
                                             pclass1_values/total*100))

    print('total: {}, pclass2: {} ({:.2f}%)'.format(total, pclass2_values,
                                                pclass2_values / total * 100))

    print('total: {}, pclass3: {} ({:.2f}%)'.format(total, pclass3_values,
                                                pclass3_values / total * 100))

input('press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Why there's 3 for loop? You can make things in one loop only.

Comment: I removed the for loops and it still doesnt work :9

Comment: Still sinking with the titanic? If you had used pandas as I suggested, you would be well on your wa to finishing your 3rd or 4th ship

Comment: not allowed to use pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `csv_reader` is a generator, which exhausts when you iterate over it, so you will need to collapse the 3 `for`-loops to one

The easiest way to get this to work would be with a counter:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

pclass_col = 0
c = Counter()
```

## read the file

```
with open('titanic-new.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')
    next(csv_reader, None)
    for row in csv_reader:
        c(int(row[pclass_col]) += 1
```

## summarise the results

```
total = sum(c.values())

classes = {
    'pclass1': (1,),
    'pclass2': (2,),
    'pclass3': (3,),
}

for pclass, pclass_values in classes.items():
    pclass_value = sum(c[k] for k in pclass_values)
    msg = 'total: {}, {}: {} ({:.2f}%)'.format(total, pclass, pclass_values, pclass_value / total * 100)
    print(msg)
```